# Microsoft Visual C# Express Edition 2008 Question

Tags: c#

I completed a project, and after I finished it I saved and closed out.
When I reopen Microsoft Visual C# Express Edition it shows me all my recent projects. When I open one I can find the Form1.cs however I can not find the code that handles all my events and everything. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please could you change your question title to something more specific?

Answer (score 5):

Try right-clicking the Form1.cs and select *View Code* (Pressing F7 should do the same).

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot but try to click the Show All Files button.  That may show you something.